# Set Like to folder (Video) from Javascript

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, javascript

Right now I get the information from a video like this:

```
var ctx = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);
var site = ctx.get_site();
var web = site.openWeb(webUrl);         
var folder = web.getFolderByServerRelativeUrl(folderUrl);
var file = folder.get_properties(); 

ctx.load(web, 'Url');
ctx.load(file);

ctx.executeQueryAsync(
    Function.createDelegate(this, function(sender, args){
        var item = file.get_fieldValues();
        var video = { 
                title: item.item.vti_title,
                description: item.item.VideoSetDescription,
                likes: item.item.LikesCount || 0
            }
        ...
    }), 
    Function.createDelegate(this, function(sender, args) {
        ...
    })
);
```

I need to set the Like for that video now with something like this:

```
Microsoft.Office.Server.ReputationModel.Reputation.setLikesetLike(context,
                        listid,
                        itemId, !liked)
```

How I get the values needed for the set?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Done it, this its the code:

```
function(siteUrl, webUrl, relativeFileUrl, itemDetails) {
    var ctx = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);
    var site = ctx.get_site();
    var web = site.openWeb(webUrl);         
    var folder = web.getFolderByServerRelativeUrl(relativeFileUrl);
    var file = folder.get_properties(); 
    var item = folder.get_listItemAllFields();  // <-- New
    ctx.load(web, 'Url');
    ctx.load(item);
    ctx.load(file);
    ctx.load(folder)  // <-- New
    ctx.executeQueryAsync(
        Function.createDelegate(this, function(sender, args){
            // success
            //console.log("Success");
            console.log(ctx);
            var video = { 
                title: item.item.vti_title,
                description: item.item.VideoSetDescription,
                likes: item.item.LikesCount || 0,
                id : item.get_id() // <--
            }
        }), 
        Function.createDelegate(this, function(sender, args) {
            // error
            ...
        })
    );
}
```